# Azure tranlate API call is returning and 40100

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services

I used this HTTP-Get request to get a Bearer token for the translation:

```
https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issueToken?Subscription-Key=1fo8xxx
```

Using the returned Bearer I wanted to translate a short text using this API endpoint:

```
https://api.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com/translate?api-version=3.0&to=de
```

In the header I put this:

```
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8.
```

And in the body I put this:

```
[
   {"Text":"I would really like to drive your car around the block a few times."}
]
```

I am using Postman, so in the authorization tab I selected Bearer and inserted in the field next to it this:

```
Bearer <result from the first API call>
```

If I send the reqeuest I get this result:

```
{"error":{"code":401000,"message":"The request is not authorized because credentials are missing or invalid."}}
```

Answer (score 7):

In case someone ever stumbles upon this, after hours of trial and error I found out you need to pass the Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Region param in the header.
Here is an example in python that I was able to run successfully.

```
import json
import requests


def translate(text, source_language, dest_language):
    if not <Secret Key>:
        return 'Error: the translation service is not configured.'
    headers = {'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': <Secret Key>,
               'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Region': <region>,
               'Content-type': 'application/json'}
    url = 'https://api.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com/translate?api-version=3.0&from={}&to={}' \
        .format(source_language, dest_language)
    body = [{'text': text}]
    request = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=body)
    if request.status_code != 200:
        return 'Error: the translation service failed.'
    return json.loads(request.content.decode('utf-8-sig'))
```

The list of regions and other examples can be found here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/translator/reference/v3-0-reference

Don't be fooled by the curl example that is not using the region..

Comment: I can concur, this was exactly what I was missing.  (Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Region)

Comment: THANK YOU!!!!! quite frankly I am losing respect and trust in Microsoft because of this. I was going insane.

Answer (score 0):

Your request needs the "OCP-Apim-Subscription-Key" header. Take a look on the official example:

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
// Install Newtonsoft.Json with NuGet
using Newtonsoft.Json;

/// <summary>
/// The C# classes that represents the JSON returned by the Translator Text API.
/// </summary>
public class TranslationResult
{
    public DetectedLanguage DetectedLanguage { get; set; }
    public TextResult SourceText { get; set; }
    public Translation[] Translations { get; set; }
}

public class DetectedLanguage
{
    public string Language { get; set; }
    public float Score { get; set; }
}

public class TextResult
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Script { get; set; }
}

public class Translation
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public TextResult Transliteration { get; set; }
    public string To { get; set; }
    public Alignment Alignment { get; set; }
    public SentenceLength SentLen { get; set; }
}

public class Alignment
{
    public string Proj { get; set; }
}

public class SentenceLength
{
    public int[] SrcSentLen { get; set; }
    public int[] TransSentLen { get; set; }
}

private const string key_var = "TRANSLATOR_TEXT_SUBSCRIPTION_KEY";
private static readonly string subscriptionKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(key_var);

private const string endpoint_var = "TRANSLATOR_TEXT_ENDPOINT";
private static readonly string endpoint = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(endpoint_var);

static Program()
{
    if (null == subscriptionKey)
    {
        throw new Exception("Please set/export the environment variable: " + key_var);
    }
    if (null == endpoint)
    {
        throw new Exception("Please set/export the environment variable: " + endpoint_var);
    }
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage())
    {
        // Build the request.
        // Set the method to Post.
        request.Method = HttpMethod.Post;
        // Construct the URI and add headers.
        request.RequestUri = new Uri(endpoint + route);
        request.Content = new StringContent(requestBody, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        request.Headers.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", subscriptionKey);

        // Send the request and get response.
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false);
        // Read response as a string.
        string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        // Deserialize the response using the classes created earlier.
        TranslationResult[] deserializedOutput = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TranslationResult[]>(result);
        // Iterate over the deserialized results.
        foreach (TranslationResult o in deserializedOutput)
        {
            // Print the detected input language and confidence score.
            Console.WriteLine("Detected input language: {0}\nConfidence score: {1}\n", o.DetectedLanguage.Language, o.DetectedLanguage.Score);
            // Iterate over the results and print each translation.
            foreach (Translation t in o.Translations)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Translated to {0}: {1}", t.To, t.Text);
            }
        }
    }
    Console.Read();
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/translator/quickstart-translate?pivots=programming-language-csharp

Comment: add the OCP-Apim-Subscription-Key header in the request: https://learning.postman.com/docs/postman/sending-api-requests/requests/#configuring-request-headers

Comment: @thiango Custodio but I dont have the associated key. do you know where I can find it?

Comment: in the azure portal. Go to your resource, then "Keys" section

Answer (score 0):

If you set not 'Global' region, then you need to add region value to 'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Region' header of request. You can find it on 'Keys and Endpoint' page of your Azure account, get letter by letter (copy and paste).

[image: 'Keys and Endpoint' page]